# Delegating static type-checking to an attribute

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, typechecking, python-typing

In Python 3.9, I'm trying to unify type and instance checks with type hint annotation for static type checking in one class. Because get_origin and get_type_hints are still in flux and I don't want to build a parser for the different typing syntax, I'm looking to create a simple class that serves both purposes until Python unifies its static and runtime typing. And I don't want any of the supported checks (static type-checking, isinstance, and issubclass) to be dependent on inheritance. Python 3.10 might solve this issue a different way with structural pattern matching, but I'm looking for a solution under 3.9. And I want to avoid importing a larger package with overhead like pydantic. This is my basic idea:

```
import abc
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
import dataclasses
from typing import Annotated, Any, Hashable, Type


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Kind(abc.ABC):

    comparison: ClassVar[Type]
    annotation: ClassVar[Annotated]
    
    @classmethod
    def __instancecheck__(cls, instance: Any) -> bool:
        return isinstance(instance, cls.comparison)
    
    @classmethod
    def __subclasscheck__(cls, subclass: Type) -> bool:
        return issubclass(subclass, cls.comparison)
```

I'm using dataclasses because they make the type declaration easy to read and compact. If that creates a problem with functionality, I can switch to ordinary classes.
The comparison class attribute holds the class to use for runtime isinstance and issubclass checks. More complicated subclasses of Kind can have greater rules and limits in the **instancecheck** and **subclasscheck** methods. That part of my solution works fine.
The annotation class attribute should hold the value to be used in type hint annotations used by static type-checkers. So, for example, this is a Dictionary subclass to Kind:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Dictionary(Kind):

    comparison: ClassVar[Type] = MutableMapping
    annotation: ClassVar[Annotated] = MutableMapping[Hashable, Any]
```

Is there any way to be able to use Kind subclasses like Dictionary as type hints without specifically including the annotation class attribute? My particular project has more complicated composite data types like adjacency lists, adjacency matrixes, trees, and other custom types.

So, I'd rather be able to do this:

```
def make_upper(dictionary: Dictionary) -> Dictionary:
```

than this:

```
def make_upper(dictionary: Dictionary.annotation) -> Dictionary.annotation:
```

I'm not sure how to go about implementing this latter part of the solution. I've tried toying around with TypeVar, Generic, and **class_getitem** but I can't seem to make them work. Basically, I just want mypy and other static type-checkers to look at the annotation attribute during testing. I just can't figure out how to delegate the static type-checking to the appropriate attribute. It seems like I'm missing something obvious. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: In short: you want to use some object in two ways: 1) in an `isinstance` or `issubclass` check; 2) as a type annotation that's understood by type checkers like mypy? I think your proposed solution works for 1 but probably not for 2. There are checker-specific solutions though, you can try writing a [mypy plugin](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html) that understands your annotations, and I suppose other checkers also support extensions and stuff.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't considered writing a mypy plugin. That could work. It would be nice if I could use a dunder method to automatically delegate the check by mypy. But the plugin is a nice alternative.